# IIS Browser caching not working

Tags: iis, caching, pagespeed

I have enabled caching in IIS 6 for all our static images and CSS(by right clicking on those folders in IIS and enabled Content Expiration after 30 days under **HTTP Headers**).

When I run Google PageSpeed, and look at the resources tab, the status of those images and css shows up as 200, but I was expecting a 304(not modified). When I checked Yahoo.com in Pagespeed, all its images have a 304 status. So my caching is not working? or is this how IIS content expiration works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the traffic with Fiddler when you retrieve those resources. Check to make sure of exactly which headers are being used on the request and the response. That may point you to something you didn't configure correctly.

Comment: The 'Net' tab in Firebug should show each request. You can examine the headers there. Also, make sure that the "Disable browser cache" option is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions!!! I never used the Net tab in firebug, but it turned out to be very helpful. 
Looks like I had 'Disable Caching' checked in my web developer toolbar and that is why I was getting a 200 status instead of 304. I disabled that and now getting 304 and my images are loading from cache!

Comment: @Karthik: If that solved the problem for you, post it as an Answer so we can mark this as solved.